# JSON file not loading into redshift

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift

I have issues using the copy command in redshift to load in JSON objects, I am receiving a file in the below JSON format which fails when attempting to use the copy command, however when I adjust the json file to the bottom it works. This is not an ideal solution as I am not permiited to modify the JSON file

this works fine :

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Major League Baseball"
}
{
   "id": 2,
   "name": "National Hockey League"
}
```

This does not work (notice the extra square brackets)

```
[
{"id":1,"name":"Major League Baseball"},
{"id":2,"name":"National Hockey League"}
]
```

this is my json path

```
{
    "jsonpaths": [
        "$['id']",
        "$['name']"
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you clarify the question a bit?

Comment: I am attempting to copy some JSON into Redshift, the trouble is the JSON contains "[" and commas (see above JSON) in areas breaking the loading in of this data, I could write a script to get around this issue but ideally i want to avoid that

Comment: Each row's worth of data needs to be a separate json object like in the first example. The jsonpaths specification is a list, but it's a list of column locators within one object. To support the second example Redshift would have to parse vast files before it could decide what values were part of a row.

Comment: can you give me an example how this could be done?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the `COPY` command is it does not really accept a valid JSON file. Instead, it expects a **JSON-per-line** which is [shown](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html) in the documentation, but not obviously mentioned.

Hence, every line is supposed to be a valid JSON but the full file is not. That's why when you modify your file, it works.